# Get Map(Types:String,Types:String) in .Net application

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, business-connector

In AX 2009 I have class with method returning Map.

In С# I have null:

```
using (Axapta Ax = new Axapta())
{
    Ax.Logon(null, null, null, null);
    AxaptaObject ax = Ax.CreateAxaptaObject("SomeClass");
    object obj = ax.Call("getMapData",1);
    Dictionary<String, String> dict = obj as Dictionary<String, String>;
```

In this code `dict` is null. Why?

Is it possible to get complex data type from AX on .Net side?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but a `Map` in X++ is not the same thing as a `Dictionary` in C#.

You can use a map though:

```
AxaptaObject map = ax.Call("getMapData",1);
```

Then call the map with:

```
String val = map.call("lookup", "key");
```

Comment: Map not have method "currentValue"... But the direction is clear - thanks!

Comment: sorry, i do not understand what else you need.
your answer helped me, but is not comlete answer. I gave a complete answer in the topic below.

Answer (score 2):

full code to do it (get Dictionary):

```
Dictionary<String,String> dict = new Dictionary<String,String>();
String key, value;

using (Axapta Ax = new Axapta())
{
    Ax.Logon(null, null, null, null);

    AxaptaObject someClass= Ax.CreateAxaptaObject("SomeClass");

    AxaptaObject map = someClass.Call("getMapData",1) as AxaptaObject;
    AxaptaObject mapIterator = Ax.CreateAxaptaObject("MapIterator", map);

    while ((bool)mapIterator.Call("more"))
    {
            key = mapIterator.Call("key").ToString();
            value = mapIterator.Call("value").ToString();

            dict.Add(key,value);

            mapIterator.Call("next");
    }

}
return dict;
```